# Fix Warning "Also define the standard property 'background-clip' for compatibility"

Tags: html, css

While i use video inside text in my webpage i saw this warning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDiDF.png)

i check on internet then i got a solution using '-webkit' but issue not resolved. need a fix on that issue

Comment: Then just include the `background-clip` property with the same value? That’s exactly what the error message says.

Comment: add `background-clip: text;` bellow the code, there are some browsers that support the feature by using `webkit` and others by simple plain `background-clip`